# Restore a copy of the encrypted database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

I have encrypted the backup using the method followed by the file server. Unfortunately, I did not keep a copy of the certificate of the process of encryption and unfortunately also the server was completely destroyed and is impossible to run again and I have to restore a copy of the database.
I have a copy of the rule but it is encrypted. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: So far what I know you cannot restore without certificate.  I know you said your server is destroyed. Was your data file location (storage/san/file share) also destroyed. Can you recover your data files and make copy to a different location?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Was the backup created by using the `BACKUP DATABASE...WITH ENCRYPTION` command? Or some encryption method on the file server?  Regardless, the whole point of the encrypted backups is to prevent someone from restoring it unless they have the encryption key (ie, certificate or password).

Comment: Does the existing database still exist somewhere?

Comment: Don't use database encryption, ever. Use full disk encryption. Since you're rebuilding anyway now's the time to do it right.

Comment: If, by some miracle, you actually created the encryption certificate in master AND you happen to have a backup of master taken after the encryption certificate was created, you 'might' be able to create a new sql instance that is at the same level as the one that got destroyed, restore the backup of master (created before the instance was destroyed), back up the certificate from the new instance and create a new certificate (from the backup) on the instance you want to restore the encrypted database to.  That technique worked in a 'simple' test on my local computer.

Answer (score 13):

> I have encrypted the backup using the method followed by the file server.

Not sure what that means.

> Unfortunately, I did not keep a copy of the certificate of the process of encryption and unfortunately also the server was completely destroyed and is impossible to run again and I have to restore a copy of the database.

That's going to be impossible. If you don't have the encryption cert, you can't restore.

> I have a copy of the rule but it is encrypted.

Rule? Not sure what a rule has to do with this.

> Is there a solution to this problem?

Tell the people that you can't restore the database and it is lost forever.

Answer (score 2):

Your best chance is to go diving through the disks of the failed server for the certificate, but putting the disks into a good server. I've recovered lots of files from failed servers that way before.